# Prevent the adobe flash player for firefox to switch from HD to SP and vice versa

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, flash, flash-player, high-definition

How can you prevent the adobe flash player to switch between High Definition quality and Standard Play quality and vice versa automatically? This is very annoying!

Does this have something to do with your internet connection, or can you prevent this with some settings? Or is this better with Googel Chrome, Safari, Opera,...? I'd like to have HD all the time obviously.

Answer (score 0):

It is directly related to the speed that it can sense your line is achieving.

You can prevent it by not switching it to Automatic - the downside is that it will no longer auto-detect your line speed & instead you will get the "Buffering…" warning

[image]

Comment: I can't select the quality. When I click on full screen I get next to my firefox icon (in the taskbar) a flash player icon. So it apparently opens in another program..

Comment: then switch it before you go to fullscreen

Comment: It is a bit simular to the eurosport player, you cannot select a quality..